# How to log changes to database every 5 minutes in a high-transaction application with C# and SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, caching, logging

Imagine this scenario:  you have a WCF web service that gets hit up to a million times a day.  Each hit contains an "Account ID" identifier.  The WCF service is hosted in a distributed ASP.NET cluster and you don't have Remote Desktop access to the server.

Your goal is to save "number of hits per hour" for each Account ID into a SQL database.  The results should look like this:

```
[Time], [AccountID], [NumberOfHits]
1 PM, Account ID (Bob), 10 hits
2 PM, Account ID (Bob), 10 hits
1 PM, Account ID (Jane), 5 hits
```

The question is:  How can you do this without connecting to a SQL server database on every hit?

Here's one solution I thought of:  Store the temporary results in a System.Web.Cache object, listen to its expiration, and on Cache Expiration, write all the accumulated data to the database when Cache expires.

Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: Any DB triggers and memory based tables in SQL server?

Comment: Nothing at all.  We can start with a blank SQL Server database if desired.

Comment: Follow-up to the original question:  If using System.Web.Caching and listening for its expiration event, what pitfalls should be avoided?  On what events should the cache be written to the database before it is lost (App Pool pre-shutdown, etc)?

Comment: Imho you will never succeed to bullet-proof this by reacting to event like appdomain shutdown or cache expiration. You will have to do very expensive calls (db call to different host) which is very unlikely to succeed in the resource constrained context of such termination events (specially app shutdown). And there is always the possibility of a plain crash. If you want reliable count updates, then you must write them locally into something like a local SQL Express instance (and perhaps let Service Broker deliver the update to cental DB) or into a local MSMQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deffered update is the key, indeed, and you are on the right path with your local cache approach. As long as you don't have a requirement to display the last-update-count on each visit, the solution is simple: update a local cache of account_id->count and periodically sweep through this cache, replace the count with 0 and add the count to the total in the database. You *may* loose some visit counts if your ASP.Net process is lost, and your display hit count is not accurate (Node 1 int he ASP farm returns it's lats count, Node 2 returns its own local one, different from Node 1).

If you must have accurate display of counts on each return result (whether this is an page return or a service return, matter little) then it gets hairy quite fast. Centralized cache like Memcache can help to create a solution, but is not trivial.

Here is how I would keep the local cache:

```
class HitCountCache
{
   class Counter 
   {
       public unsigned int count {get;set}
       public accountid {get;set}
   };

   private Dictionary<accountType, Counter> _counts = new Dictionary<...>();
   private Object _lock= new Object();

   // invoke this on every call
   //
   void IncrementAccountId (accountId)
   {
      Counter count;
      lock(_lock) 
      {
         if (_counts.TryGetValue (accountId, out count))
         {
            ++count.count;
         }
         else
         {
            _counts.Add (accountId, 
                new Counter {accountId = accountId; count=0});
         }
      }
   } 

   // Schedule this to be invoked every X minutes
   //
   void Save (SqlConnection conn)
   {
      Counter[]  counts;

      // Snap the counts, under lock
      //
      lock(_lock)
      {
          counts = _counts.ToArray();
          _counts.Clear();
      }

      // Lock is released, can do DB work
      //
      foreach(Counter c in counts)
      {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                 @"Update table set count+=@count where accountId=@accountId", 
                 conn);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", c.count);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountId", accountId);
          cmd.ExecuteNoQuery();
      }
   } 
}
```

This is a skeleton, it can be improved, and can also be made to return the current total count if needed, at least the total count as known by local node.

Comment: Right.  I believe this page describes it in more detail: http://aspnetcache.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/asp-net-cache-limitations/#more-145

Answer (score 0):

One option is to dump the relevant information into your server logs (logging APIs are already optimised to deal with high transaction volumes) and reap them with a separate process.

Comment: Marcelo, would that work with a server that we don't have remote access to?  It's a distributed cluster... think of it like a hosted ASP.net provider.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but probably not. You would need filesystem-level access to the logs, and the ability to run background processes, either permanently-running or scheduled at, say, five-minute intervals. It might also be possible to use logging APIs with a listener thread that does the batching up. However, any in-memory batching solution runs the risk of losing data. Nothing beats harvesting logs, IMO.

Comment: Right.  So this is actually a pretty hard problem to solve.  Opening one million SQL connections to a remote SQL data warehouse is not feasible, so let's come up with something better.  It would be a lot easier to open one connection every 5 minutes, or every hour, and execute "update SummaryLog set NumberOfHits = NumberOfHits + @newCountFromCache where accountID = @accountID"

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "How can you do this without connecting to a SQL server database on every hit?"

Use connection pooling. With connection pooling a several connection to SQL server opened ONCE and then they are reused for subsequent calls. So on each database hit, you do not need to connect to SQL server, because you will already be connected and can reuse existing connection for you database access.

Note, that connection pooling is used by default with SQL ado.net provider, so you might be using already without even knowing it.

Comment: One problem is scalability:  If you have a web farm of 100 web servers all running the same WCF service, the SQL server might get bogged down from a constant stream of updates coming from 100 different open connections. I think your solution is valid, but it would not handle SQL going down gracefully - results would be lost if the SQL database could not be updated immediately.

Comment: The problem is not the connection, is the write. Every page visit attempts to update an account_id, your scalability quickly goes down the drain for two reasons: 1) sheer amount of writes (1 per page hit) and 2) contention on updating the same account_id in the database leads to serialization of pages requests that visit the same account. Connection pooling helps nothing.

Comment: Remus, any advice?  You seem to know this topic in depth.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: I agree that connection pooling does not help as much with performance issues as being able to hit database less frequently. However it accurately answers the question  Yakov-MIK asked: "How can you do this without connecting to a SQL server database on every hit?"

Comment: @zespri: I interpret the OP question 'How can you do this without sending a (write) request to the database on every hit?'

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: yes, this question makes much more sense in the context described.

Comment: @Yakov-MIK: if sql goes down you can (hypothetically) store the failed update in memory and re-try later. If your web service app domain goes down however, all your accumulated results will be lost irrecoverably.

Answer (score 0):

An in-memory object as proposed is fastest but risks data loss in the event of an app or server crash. To reduce data loss you can lazy-write the cached data to disk. Then periodically read back from the cache file and write the aggregated information to your SQL server.

Comment: How would you periodically poll each machine if you cannot install a service on the server?  Remember that this is inside a shared hosting environment with no direct access.  Everything must be in a self-contained ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why they aren't using app fabric or the like?

Can you get into the service implementation? If so, the way to hit this is to have the service implementation fire a "fire and forget" style logging call to whatever other service you've setup to log this puppy. Shouldn't hold up the execution, should survive app crashes and the like and won't require digging into the SQL angle.

I honestly wouldn't take the job if I couldn't get into the front end of things, most other approaches are doomed to fail here.

Comment: Wyatt, that sounds like a great idea, but it needs a code sample or a better explanation.  How do you implement "fire and forget" style logging in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is performance on the website then like another poster said, just use fire and forget. This could be a WebService that you post the data to or you can create a service running in the background listening on an MSMQ queue. I can give you more examples of this if interested. If you need to keep the website or admin tool in sync with the database you can store the values in a high performance cache like memcache at the same time you update the database.

If you want to run a batch of 100 queries on the DB in one query then make a separate service, again with MSMQ, which polls the queue and waits for > 100 messages in the queue. Once it detects there is 100 messages it opens a transaction with MSTDC and reads all the messages into memory and batches them up to run in one query. MSMQ durable, meaning that if the server shuts off or the service is down when the message is sent, it will still get delivered when the service comes online. Messages will only be removed from the queue once the query has completed. If the query errors out or something happens to the service the messages will still be in the queue for processing, you don't loose anything. MSTDC just helps you keep everything in one transaction so if one part of the process fails everything gets rolled back.

If you can't make a windows service to do this then just make a WebService that you call. You still send the MSMQ message each time a page loads, and say once every 10 times the page loads you fire the web service to process all the messages in the queue. The only problem you might have is getting the MSMQ service installed, however many hosting places and install something like this for you if you request it.